# C: Is there a good way to limit/restrict output from unrestricted scanf string

Tags: c, string

Is there a good way to limit/restrict output from scanf string? If I test it with one restiction only one restriction like '.' it shows what I expected.

```
if (b[i] == '.')
  {
  
  printf("%c", b[i]);
  }
```

But once I try to add more it doesn't restrict anything anymore.

```
if (b[i] == '.','-')
  {
  
  printf("%c", b[i]);
  }
```

Is there a good way to define what characters are allowed for output after getting an unrestricted input?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char b[5];
  int i;
 
  printf("enter characters (only first 5 allowed characters will be shown):");
  scanf("%s", b); 
  
  
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
  
  if (b[i] == '.','-')
     {
     printf("%c", b[i]);
     }
  else
     {
     i++;
     }
 }
  
  printf("\n");
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%4s", b);` avoids buffer overflows when `b` is defined as `char b[5];`, keep in mind that there is a trailing `'\0'` that occupies 1 byte, so this assumption: "enter max 5 allowed characters:" is wrong, should be "enter max 4 allowed characters:". If this is not a homework, switch to `fgets` and forget `scanf`. Also: `if (b[i] == '.','-')` does not do what you think it does, you want `if ((b[i] == '.') || (b[i] == '-'))`.

Comment: Sorry I think I put it wrong. The input shouldn't be restricted to 5. The input is not meant to really be restricted. After the input, the output should be restricted to 5 but should now be filtered from unallowed characters and only output allowed ones. Thanks for the other advice though.

Comment: `if(b[i] == '.','-')` Where did you get the idea that would work?  There's no such syntax.  I think you want `if(b[i] == '.' || b[i] == '-')`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (b[i] == '.','-')` acts like:

```
b[i] == '.';  // Compare and ignore result
if ('-')      // Test if '-' is non-zero (which it is)
```

Clearly not what OP wants.

---

Instead

```
if (b[i] == '.' || b[i] == '-') // perform up to 2 compares
```

or

```
if (memchr(".=", b[i], 2)) // Test if b[i] is in the 2 char of ".="
```

or

```
if (strchr(".=", b[i])) // Test if b[i] is in the 3 char of ".="
```

This last one is true when `b[i] == '\0'`, so is not quite the same.

If the loop was `for(j = 0; b[j]; j++)`, then the test `strchr(".=", b[j])` would not occur when `b[j] == '\0'`,  and then `strchr(".=", b[j])` would be an equivalent test.

---

Do not use `scanf("%s", b);` as it is prone to buffer over-run.  Use `fgets()` or a width limit like `scanf("%4s", b);`.

---

Code also needs to separate the indexes used to walk the input string from the count of allowed characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char b[100];
  int i = 0;
  printf("Enter characters (only first 5 allowed characters will be shown):");
  if (fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin)) {
    for (int j = 0; b[j] && i < 5; j++) {
      if (strchr(".=", b[j])) {
        printf("%c", b[j]);
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```